# Matplotlib imshow adjacent images with anomalous whitespace - is there a way to correct it?

Tags: image, plot, matplotlib, antialiasing

I am plotting tiled images in a similar way to the working code shown below:

```
import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy

def r():
    return random.randrange(50,200)

imsize = 100
rngsize = 5

rng = range(rngsize)
for i in rng:
    for j in rng:
        im = Image.new('RGB', (imsize, imsize), (r(),r(),r()))
        plt.imshow(im, aspect='equal', extent=numpy.array([i, i+1, j, j+1])*imsize)

plt.xlim(-5,imsize * rngsize + 5)
plt.ylim(-5,imsize * rngsize + 5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The problem is: as you pan and zoom, zoomscale-independent white stripes appear between the image edges, which is very undesireable. I guess this has to do with resampling and antialiasing, but have no idea how to solve it "the right way", specialy for not knowing exact implementation details of matplotlib's rendering engine.

With Cairo and HTML Canvas, you can draw "to the pixel corner" or "to the pixel center" (translating by 0.5 pixel) thus avoiding anti-aliasing effects. Would there be a way to do that with Matplotlib?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply fill in the values to a larger numpy array and plot the entire composite image in one shot. I've adapted your code above for a minimal example but with different sized images you'll need to take a different step size.

```
F = numpy.zeros((imsize*rngsize,imsize*rngsize,3))

for i in rng:
    for j in rng:
        F[i*imsize:(i+1)*imsize, 
          j*imsize:(j+1)*imsize, :] = (r(), r(), r())

plt.imshow(F, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's a fine idea, and I probably could do that with my source images with good speed, I think (mpl would have to do it anyway, I guess). But still it hits me as some sort of workaround, yet. If I don't get any magical alternative, I'll come back to accept this. Thank you very much!

Comment: @heltonbiker I admit it seems like a hack, but in the end you have a much finer control over the composite image if you want to apply any postfilters. In addition, if you want to save the composite image this is exactly the method I'd use (and bypass PIL and matplotlib entirely!)

Comment: Actually I want to make a panning map "program" using matplotlib directly as the GUI. One goal is to load and unload tiles as the map is panned, always plotting only the needed images. This may or may not be lighter than generating a new image EACH TIME I release the mouse (which is the event I plan to use to refresh the list of tiles to be plotted). Most probably, using your answer will solve the problem, so I'll only wait a bit more before accepting, just in case.

Comment: @heltonbiker You might try to load an array _larger_ than the viewport (say 3-4 tiles out in each direction) so you don't have to reload the array on each mouse movement. Only reload when your "buffer" gets to be ~ 1 title. You'll get a massive speedup at the cost of some extra memory.